# How to specify bound for a generic type with generic type in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, bounds

*This question is about working with generic types and setting the bound, so please do not freak out because of the library I use. Treat it as an example.*

I work with Scalala and use such types `DenseMatrix[V]`, `DenseVectorCol[V]` and `DenseVectorRow[V]`. The common super type for them is `Tensor[K,V]`. Note that the `Tensor` has additional parameter `K` -- all the mentioned classes `Dense...` set this type `K` by themselves.

So I would like to write a method with argument which upper type bound is `Tensor`. I wrote such code for my method:

```
def validate[K,T <: Tensor[K,Double]](tensor : T) : T = ...
```

with such intention -- `T` has to be subtype of `Tensor`, and I know I work with `Double`s all the time, so let it be `Double`, and for first type argument (`K`) get it from passed argument.

It does not work as I expected because I get error:

> inferred type arguments [Nothing,DenseVectorCol[Double]] do not conform to method validate's type parameter bounds [K,T <: Tensor[K,Double]]

**QUESTION**: so how to extract this type `K` from the passed argument?

Comment: Note that `Tensor` gives you access to its type parameter `K` through its type member `Domain`, which might make it a little easier to get by with `def validate[T <: X[_, Double]] ...` (which will be inferred correctly).

Comment: @TravisBrown, bingo -- wildcard `_` does the job (I put `Tensor` instead of `X` of course). Why didn't you post a regular answer? Please do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about `K` at all, you can use a wildcard:

```
def validate[T <: Tensor[_, Double]]: T = ...
```

Note that in some cases this wouldn't work (e.g., if you needed to return a `K` or otherwise use it in the method), but assuming this isn't one of those cases, this is a perfectly valid solution and the type inference will work out just fine.